# TortoiseGit Apply patch serial

Tags: tortoisegit

Im trying to apply serial patch files (like 22 serial patch files) and when I have a merge issue using tortoise, patch stops, i manually fix the conflict, but the patch never resumes.

Anyone knows a good tutorial or video that explains how to do it with tortoise git? (using latest version)

Tx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this is the best that I have found
https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-patch.html